# Why is this table cell behaving like this?

Tags: html, css, css-tables

Check out this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qmqgm/)**.

This is the basic CSS of `td`:

```
td {
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    background-color: rgb(141, 176, 248);
}
```

There is one cell with a 30px image. But still, that cell is 600px in width. Does anyone understand why?

Comment: What do you want the table to look like ? You aren't setting any width attributes on the cells, so it is doing whatever it wants.

Comment: Id's shouldn't start with a numeric character. It has nothing to do with your question though.

Comment: @Brainfeeder thanks, I forgot about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with `td` having content and `td` having no content.

```
Whenever your td doesn't have any fixed width
```

Since your table has `width:100%`, and there is no content in most of the td's hence they align to negligible width. But as soon as you give a content to any of the td's that entire column expand accordingly to accommodate entire width of the table.

To test it out, just even write a word in any other `td`,and entire column will get expanded.

What you should do is to provide a width to your TDs to restrict this default expansion'

```
.ui-droppable
{
   width:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the width/height to 30px and 1px border around. The image also has 30px width. Unfortunately the border width must be included in the width. You must set width to `30+2*1px`: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qmqgm/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set any width to the `<td>` element and your `<table>` hasn't any width (so it defaults to 100%) the `<td>`-s will automatically fill the whole width. In your case it is that one `<td>` that expands.

set the width in your css file and the problem should be fixed.

```
td { width:30px; }
```

Obviously you should set the table width to whatever the total of all columns is.
Or you can set the width of the table in px/% and the width of the columns in %.
Or you can use javascript/jQuery to make the columns width adapt to the image width inside it.